# Ansible async_status fails when the async call interrupts the target network connection

Tags: asynchronous, ansible, timeout, host, winrm

How can I call a task that temporarily interrupts network connectivity to the target when it runs.

I wrote a PowerShell ansible module that modifies the target windows network settings causing it to lose connectivity for around 30 seconds. The connection is to a windows 2019 server via winrm  I need to know if the task succeeded or reports errors.

If I call the task normally, it will fail with `host unreachable` if the network is gone for more than `read timeout (30)` seconds.  The operation may have succeeded, but I don't have access to its return values.

```yaml
- win_vswitch:
    Name: "SomeSwitch"
    VLAN: 123
    state: present
```

Seems like a good use of async:

```yaml
- name: Configure VSwitch
  win_vswitch:
    Name: "SomeSwitch"
    VLAN: 123
    state: present
  async: 600
  poll: 0
  register: async_result

- name: vswitch - wait for the async task to finish
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ async_result.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: task_result
  until: task_result.finished
  # ignore_unreachable: yes
  retries: 60
  delay: 5
  # failed_when: False
```

The problem is that if the `async_status` poll is unable to get a network connection to the target for more than `read_timeout` seconds, it fails with host unreachable error.  Even if the `async_status`'s timeouts haven't expired.

Seems to me that I just need to set the read timeout to a higher value.  And that's where I'm stuck.

Things I've tried:

- `timeout` in ansible.cfg
- `ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec` & `ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec` in the inventory host item
- `ignore_unreachable` & `failed_when` in the `async_status` module
- rescue clause around the `async_status`

Suggestions?
TIA, Jeff

Comment: See [`win_wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_wait_for_module.html) or [`wait_for_connection`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_connection_module.html). Add a task to wait for the host interface to be available again prior to polling the async status.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `ansible_winrm_connection_timeout` (and other `ansible_winrm_*` values as well), by defining vars on the task itself:

```yaml
- name: vswitch - wait for the async task to finish
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ async_result.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: task_result
  until: task_result.finished
  retries: 60
  delay: 5
  vars:
    ansible_winrm_connection_timeout: 300
```

This may be preferable to using the `win_wait_for` task depending upon the use case.  `win_wait_for` might be good for a task when the network connectivity will immediately drop; however, if you have a task that will cause a drop at a random time (like a task installing network drivers).